# Proving $ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (n^2-k^2) = \frac{(2n)!}{2}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, products

I'm probably having a brain-fart but I can't figure out why this identity holds:

$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (n^2-k^2) = \frac{(2n)!}{2}
$$

I tried using various formulae involving $\binom{2n}{n}$, without success. Any ideas?

Bonus if it helps *visualise* why the factors on the RHS, involving squares, would multiply to get the RHS, which does not contain any square terms.

Comment: Well, i'd start by noting that $(n^2-k^2)=(n-k)(n+k)$, so that the product on the left runs from $n-(n-1)=1 $ to $n+n-1=2n-1$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for confirming my brain-fart. Now it all looks so obvious. I guess lockdown is starting to have effects on my thinking...

Comment: But what was your thinking here? Which number theoretic problem did you work on, needing this? A new idea for the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde No, I am just going over Van der Poorten's paper on the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$. I find it a very interesting read. But I am impressed by how quickly you made a link between my question and Apéry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation: We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(n^2-k^2\right)}
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(n-k)\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(n+k)\\
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)\cdot n\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(n+k)\tag{1}\\
&=n!\cdot n\cdot \frac{(2n-1)!}{n!}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}(2n)!}
\end{align*}
and the claim follows.

In (1) we change the order of multiplication in the left-hand product $k\to n-1-k$ and split the factor $n$ from the right-hand product